# XPATH / ElementTree - How to get next element that is not a child

Tags: xpath, elementtree

i want to search for a specific element `<B>` if `<B>`'s child `<C>` equals the string `s1` i want to search from that element on to the next element `<X>` that is NOT a child of `<B>` and return its value (`s2`).

The tree would look something like this:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>s1</C>
    </B>
    <D>
        <X>s2</X>
    </D>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)

```
//X[preceding::B[C='s1']][not(parent::A)]/text()
```